# My listener does not saves data to the table

Tags: laravel, events, listener

I have created an event-listener that before updating `team_members` table should save the row to the `team_members_log` table. Currently, nothing happens no errors no inserts either. I am not sure if the `event` gets fired at all.

My Model, I am dispatching the event from:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Events\TeamMemberUpdating;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class TeamMember extends Model
{
    use Notifiable; 

    protected $table = 'team_members';

    protected $fillable = ['project_request_id'];

    protected $dispatchesEvents = [
        'updating' => TeamMemberUpdating::class,
    ];
}
```

The event itself:

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use App\Models\TeamMember;

class TeamMemberUpdating extends Event
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $teamMember;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(TeamMember $teamMember)
    {
        $this->teamMember = $teamMember;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    /*public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
    }*/
}
```

The listener:

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Models\TeamMemberLog;
use App\Events\TeamMemberUpdating;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class LogTeamMemberWithProjectRequest
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  TeamMemberUpdating  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(TeamMemberUpdating $event)
    {   
        TeamMemberLog::create(['name' => $event->teamMember->name, 'title'=> $event->teamMember->title, 'picture' => $event->teamMember->picture, 'email' => $event->teamMember->email, 'phone_number' => $event->teamMember->phonenumber, 'background-information' => $event->teamMemmber->background_information ]);
    }
}
```

registering them:

```
 protected $listen = [
        Registered::class => [
            SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
        ],
        'App\Events\TeamMemberUpdating' => [
            'App\Listeners\LogTeamMemberWithProjectRequest',
        ],
    ];
```

Comment: Did you [register your event & listener](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/events#registering-events-and-listeners) combination?

Comment: yep. updated above.

Comment: It might be caching, did you run `event:clear`?

Comment: I tried but did not help. I am not sure if my listener handle method logic is right? Should `$event->teamMember` contain all the values I want to save ?